# Is it possible for the destructor to NOT call the destructor of a specific field?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using a C++ compiler with the `-std=c++0x` flag.

I am writing a simulation for a virtual memory system for class and have ran into a problem:

One of the classes, `VirtualMemory`, initializes several objects of a different class called `OurPointer` by giving them an integer and a pointer to itself.

The program runs several pointers that are all linked to the same virtual memory.
the constructor of `OurPointer` looks like so:

```
OurPointer::OurPointer(int adr , VirtualMemory* vrtlMem)
{
    _adr = adr;
    _vrtlMem = vrtlMem;
}
```

This is because `OurPointer` is used to work with `VirtualMemory`. The problem is, every time an `OurPointer` object is destroyed, it calls the destructor of `_vrtlMem`, which points to the same `VirtualMemory` object that is still used by the program.

Is there a way to exclude that field from the destructor? I tried to turn it into a static field, or change the pointer but it didn't stop the destructor.

Comment: That's weird. Destruction of `_vrtlMem` should not deallocate the memory pointed by it, it will only destroy the pointer itself. Are you sure that you are not deallocating the memory yourself?

Comment: If you store only a pointer to the virtual memory, no destructor gets called in the first place

Comment: My guess is that vrtlMem's destructor is called because the object is going out of scope where it was created, not because of OurPointer being destroyed.

Comment: What is `_vrtlMem`??? What type does it have? If it is also a pointer of `VirtualMemory*` type, just like `vrtlMem` parameter, then your problem description is misleading. Raw pointers in C++ do not have destructors.

Comment: Off topic: [On the off chance you don't know the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), be careful with underscore prefixes.

Comment: Hard to say much of value without more information. An [mcve] would be good, but this may be answerable with the definition of `OurPointer` and `~OurPointer::OurPointer`

Comment: We can answer the question in your title, but I'm pretty sure that won't solve your problem. If you want help with that, you should provide an [mcve](/help/mcve) as suggested by user4581301.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, every time an OurPointer object is destroyed, it calls the destructor of _vrtlMem

That would be true only if:

1. you have coded a destructor to do that, eg:

   ```
   OurPointer::~OurPointer()
   {
       delete _vrtlMem;
   }
   ```
2. `_vrtlMem` is a smart pointer like `std::auto_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, which destroy the pointed-to object when they are themselves destructed.

> which points to the same VirtualMemory object that is still used by the program.

That is exactly the kind of situation that C++11's [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) was designed for. A shared object will not be destructed until all references to it have been cleared.

Since you are not using C++11, you could use [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) instead, or you could just implement reference counting manually.

> Is there a way to exclude that field from the destructor?

If `_vrtlMem` is a smart pointer, no.  But `shared_ptr` handles reference counting for you.

Otherwise, if `_vrtlMem` is just a raw pointer, simply don't destruct the pointed-to object when you don't want it destructed.